# org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.<init>([Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)V Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am getting below error when I simply run the code from : https://github.com/schacko-samples/s1p-2019-scst-kafka-talk/tree/master/hello-streams-application.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-05 11:29:56.783 ERROR 24712 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.JsonMessageConverter.<init>(JsonMessageConverter.java:47)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.<init>([Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)V

The method's class, org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/messaging/converter/AbstractMessageConverter.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter
```

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the wrong (mismatched) version of spring-messaging on the class path. That method was added in Spring Framework 5.2.2.

I see the pom for that project is using snapshots.

I think Hoxton switched from Boot 2.2 to 2.3 around SR5.

In the pom, try changing the Boot starter to 2.3.9.RELEASE and the Hoxton version to `Hoxton.SR10`.

If that doesn't work, try Boot 2.2.13.RELEASE and Hoxton.SR4.

Comment: Spring Boot is updated to `2.3.9.RELEASE` and spring cloud to `Hoxton.SR10`. All the projects in this repository are now building fine. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please guide here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490619/caused-by-com-fasterxml-jackson-core-jsonparseexception-unrecognized-token-%c3%bf?